# MQ: Queue is not able to accept 4 MB of message

Tags: ibm-mq

Queue is not able to accept message greater than 4 MB even though MAXMSGL set to 100 MB on the Queue Manager, Queue, DLQ, SVRCONN and CLNTCONN and provided updated channel tab to application team.  This didn't resolved the issue (restarted queue manager as well).

Application team is posting the messages using service/job.

Whereas same job is able to connect and post 4+ MB of message to different queue manager running on different server.

MQ Client Version: 7.5.0.2
MQ Server Version: 7.5.0.3

I tried to post 4+ MB message to the queue using RFHUtil it is successful. But somehow it is failing to send message from application/job.

Answer (score 1):

Issue found once we enabled trace on the client machine. It is observed application is using old channel tab even though entries in environment variables referring to new channel tab. 
Restarted MQ Client machine and tested flow by enabling trace and this time it worked as expected and application/job able to post the message greater than 4 MB.